# Wi-fi at airports in Japan and South Korea

Tags: airports, japan, south-korea, internet, wifi

I want to know whether there is free Wi-Fi available at the major airports in Japan and Korea. If not then what's the best way to get access to the Internet while waiting for flights to kill some time?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, all three major airports (Haneda, Narita, and Kansai) in Japan provide free Wi-Fi. And in South Korea, Incheon International Airport also provides free Wi-Fi.

You can learn how to connect to it by the following links:

- [Japan](http://www.deepjapan.org/a/2448)
- [South Korea](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/seoul.htm#wifi)

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder What is your source of it? According to [this page](http://airport.tokyu-agc.co.jp/airport_1_1.html) which refers to the statistics by Ministry of Land, Infrastructure, Transport, and Tourism, the top three in 2015 are Haneda, Narita, Kansai, both for international and total (though I'm sure the OP assume international only).

Comment: @Blaszard Apologies, I was using 2013 data. 2015 data (the most recent publication) does have Kansai 3rd in passenger movements for the first time ever. Forgive my ignorance in not checking the most current data. Here is the MLIT report for 2015 if you were wondering: http://www.mlit.go.jp/common/001141843.pdf I shall delete the comment.